# Help find closed form: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k{m\choose k}{n-ka\over (n+m-k)^m}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

We observe the double sum:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^k{m\choose k}{n-ka\over (n+m-k)^m}=f(m,a),m\ge2\tag1$$
>   $a$ is not restricted

We are trying to determine the closed form for $(1)$

Let expanded $(1)$ for $m=2,3$ and $4$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (n+2)^2}-2\cdot{n-a\over (n+2)^2}+{n-2a\over n^2}=f(2,a)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (n+3)^3}-3\cdot{n-a\over (n+2)^3}+3\cdot{n-2a\over (n+2)^3}-{n-3a\over n^3}=f(3,a)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{n\over (n+4)^4}-4\cdot{n-a\over (n+3)^4}+6\cdot{n-2a\over (n+2)^4}-4\cdot{n-3a\over (n+1)^4}+{n-4a\over n^4}=f(4,a)$$

We was able to determine the closed form for

$$f(2,a)=1-2a$$
$$f(3,a)={7\over8}(3a-1)$$
$$f(4,a)={575\over 648}(1-4a)$$

By the look of it, we can assume the general closed form $(1)$ might take the form of $$f(m,a)=(-1)^m(1-ma)g(m)$$

> How can we find the general closed form for $(1)$?

Comment: The denominator of $g(3)$ factors to be $2^3$. The denominator of $g(4)$ factors to be $2^3 3^4$. Perhaps writing out $g(m)$ for a few more values might make a pattern apparent.

Comment: Well @CodeLabMaster that is the problem, I can't write more g(m) values, because I don't know it.